# Fluids at rest - hydrostatics

Tags: pressure

Why does pressure force of a fluid at rest act perpendicular on surface area of a body? How to prove that?
On the picture below, on the most right layer we have  Ft + mg = N (normal reaction from the bottom) How comes that Ft = 0?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the pressure did not act perpendicular to the body, it would have a tangential component. According to Newton's third law, the body would exert an equal and opposite force on the fluid layer in contact with the body. A fluid cannot resist a tangential (shear) force, so it would no longer stay in equilibrium if the pressure acted at any angle other than normal to the body's surface.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, a fluid is any substance that flows or deforms under an applied shear stress. A fluid at rest cannot have a shear stress on it, otherwise it could not remain at rest.  Since a static fluid cannot have a shear stress, it cannot impose a shear stress on a container (Newton's third law).